# c char pointers memory and global variables

Tags: c, pointers

The pointer to my global variable is turning to crud after freeing the local resource that I use to set the value in c.

this is the .c class

```
char* resource_directory;
void getResourcePath()
{
  char *basePath = SDL_GetBasePath();
  char* resource_dir = (char*)malloc(37 * sizeof(char));

  for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
    resource_dir[i] = basePath[i];
  }
  strcat(resource_dir, "resources/");
  resource_dir[36] = '\0';

  *resource_directory = *resource_dir;
  free(basePath);
  // free(resource_dir); <--- If I free here the value goes to crud
}
```

(this line below should say the value at resresource_directorydir equals the value at resource_dir) right?

```
*resource_directory = *resource_dir;
```

so the value at the address of the first pointer should get the value of the address at the 2nd but after trying to free the resource towards the end of the function.

even doing a print statement of the addresses show that they have different addresses.

```
SDL_Log("%d, %d", &resource_directory, &resource_dir);
```

example output `: 245387384, 1361037488`

I get the feeling that I am making a silly mistake here but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Do not cast `malloc()`'s return value, and do not use `sizeof(char)` since it's always 1,  and do not print addresses with the `"%d"` specifier, use `"%p"`.

Comment: @this (who deleted comment) in this context, using `sizeof(*resource_dir)` is better since it will survive a change of type without needing attention.

Comment: Is this a C++ or C question? If the question is C++ the answers can be very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line,

```
*resource_directory = *resource_dir;
```

is assigning the first value `resource_dir` points to, to the uninitialized pointer `resource_directory`, it's equivalent to

```
resource_directory[0] = resource_dir[0];
```

which is clearly not what you want.

You need to assign the pointer

```
resource_directory = resource_dir;
```

but you shouldn't use a global variable for that, and specially

1. Don't `malloc()` it, you have to `free()` everything you `malloc()` and global variables make it hard.
2. Don't use `malloc()` for fixed size objects, instead declare it as an array with the appropriate size, like this

   ```
   char resource_directory[37];
   ```
3. Copy strings with `strcpy()` instead of writing a loop your self

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
       resource_dir[i] = basePath[i];
    }
   ```

   woule be

   ```
   strcpy(resource_dir, basePath);
   ```
4. One thing you should notice when using a global variable like this is that if you call `getResourcesPath()` more than once, you are going to leak resources, if you **must** use global variables to carry values that need to live as long as the whole program lives, try to make their initialization static, and you can completely avoid using global variables for that, because everything that you declare and initialized in the stack frame of `main()` will hafe the same lifetime as the program, so you can pass it as parameters to any function that requires them from within `main()`, if you have many of these variables, create a struct to hold them, and pass the struct across the functions that need these resources, this is a very common technique in fact.

Comment: this was it. I was bashing my head against the wall for a few hours and then I realized that I never initialized resource_directory!

Comment: thanks for the more detailed follow up as well. Can you expand on not using global variables? I have two functions, one called getresourcepath() that sets the global variable for the resource path. Then I can do getresource("shaders/vertexshader") which would use the global resource path + this string to reach in and get the required resource as a string so that I can load it. What do you mean setup static variables in main? currently this code is in a .c file, the header is included in main? I tried moving resouce_directory[37] to main.c but I cannot see the char array.

Answer (score 0):

This statements

```
SDL_Log("%d, %d", &resource_directory, &resource_dir);
```

outputs as integer values the addresses of global variables `resource_directory` and local variable `resource_dir`. Of course their addresses are different.

As for this statement

```
*resource_directory = *resource_dir;
```

then it stores the first character of the string pointed to by `resource_dir` at the address that is stored in pointer `resource_directory`. However  initially `resource_directory` was initialized by zero as an object with the static storage duration. So the program has undefined behaviour.

I think you mean the following

```
resource_directory = resource_dir;
```

That is you wanted that `resource_directory` would point to the string built in the function.

And there is no sense to use statement

```
free(resource_dir); <--- If I free here the value goes to crud
```

necause in this case statement

```
resource_directory = resource_dir;
```

also does not have sense.

If `resource_directory` need to point to the built in the function string then you shall not destroy it.

Take into account that using magic numbers 37 and 25 makes the program unclear and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a variable that contains a numeric value which happens to be the address of a memory location. For example, a NULL pointer is a variable containing the value 0. Assigning the notion of "isa pointer" to is a way of notifying the compiler of your intended use: that is, you cannot use pointer syntax on non-pointer variables. But until you do use pointer syntax, they more or less behave like normal variables.

```
int i = 0;
int* p = &i;

int j;
int* q;

j = i; // j has the same value as i
q = p; // q has the same value as p
```

At the end of the above code, `p` and `q` point to the same address. We only use the `*` syntax when we want to *dereference* a pointer:

```
q = p;
*q = *p; // copies the `int` pointed to by `p` to
// the `int` memory location pointed to by `q`,
// which is the same location.
```

Note that it is possible to nest pointers:

```
int** pp = &p;
```

`p` is `int*`, so `&p` is `int**`.

`pp` is a numeric value, it is the address of a memory location that contains an `int*`. `*pp` means `fetch the value at the memory location contained in pp` which will retrieve a second numeric value - the value that is in `p`, which is itself an `int*` and thus a second address. `**pp` will retrieve us the integer to which `p` points.

Your assignment

```
*resource_directory = *resource_dir;
```

copies the pointed-to-values, not the addresses.

Since you have tagged your question as C++ I'm going to conclude by offering this alternative implementation:

```
std::string resource_dir;
void getResourcePath()
{
    char *basePath = SDL_GetBasePath();
    resource_dir = base_path;
    resource_dir += "resources/";
    free(basePath);
}
```

If you need the c-string value of resource_dir subsequently, use `resource_dir.c_str()`.

Alternatively, if you require a C implementation:

```
char* resource_dir;
void getResourcePath()
{
    const char subPath[] = "resources/";
    size_t length;
    char *basePath = SDL_GetBasePath();
    if (resource_dir)
        free(resource_dir);
    length = strlen(basePath) + sizeof(subPath);
    resource_dir = (char*)malloc(length);
    snprintf(resource_dir, length, "%s%s", basePath, subPath);
    free(basePath);
}
```